# Application token/secrets when creating an OAuth API

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, oauth

Background: I am using node.js and express to create an API. I have implemented OAuth in my API server in a standard consumer/user key/secret fashion (the same way Twitter, Facebook, etc. do). I expect 3rd parties to connect to my API, again in the same manner as these common APIs.

Normally, a client would connect with an application token/secret (eg, you create a Facebook app as a Facebook developer and these are given to you). However there are times when the client cannot provide a secret for the application because the code is implemented in an insecure fashion. Specifically, I am referring to Javascript libraries. Eg, developers do not want to expose their application secret in Javascript code because it is plaintext and could be read by malicious users.

I've noticed that Facebook avoided this problem. The developer needs to provide only an application token (not secret) to the Javascript library. I do not understand how to provide a similar option for my API without fundamentally making my library insecure. Namely, if requests are being made by a Javascript client library to an API without providing a well-secured token/secret, how are those requests authenticated by the OAuth API?

Intellectually, the best solution I could think of would to have some sort of token handoff between the Javascript client library and the API server via a HTTPS connection, in order to return a secret for the library to use. I'm not quite sure how I'd secure this handoff to prevent spoofs, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases it is better to follow the standards than to implement some custom way. OAuth2 specifies [4 methods in the latest draft (28)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-28#page-8) to do the Authorization Grant flow. The *implicit* flow is the one you saw on Facebook.

As the standard says for that:

> When issuing an access token during the implicit grant flow, the authorization server does not authenticate the client.  In some cases, the client identity can be verified via the redirection URI used to deliver the access token to the client.  The access token may be exposed to the resource owner or other applications with access to the resource owner's user-agent.
>
> Implicit grants improve the responsiveness and efficiency of some clients (such as a client implemented as an in-browser application) since it reduces the number of round trips required to obtain an access token.  However, this convenience should be weighed against the security implications of using implicit grants, especially when the authorization code grant type is available.

it has some security drawbacks.

But as far as I can see, the other methods don't work for you, as they are exposing secrets to either the client (third-party website owner) or the resource owner (user), so you should stay with this.

Comment: Ah, it took me a couple readings of that, but it makes sense now. Definitely adds some work to my implementation, but you're right, it sounds like my best available option. There is a certain elegance to using the redirect URL to authenticate, though.